# Finding one string located in another

Tags: c, strings

Can anyone help me improve my `instr()` function?

```
int myInstr(wchar_t *str, wchar_t c, int start, int dir){
    int pos = 0, result = 0, len;
    wchar_t *p1;

    //Left
    if(dir == 0)
    {
        p1 = str;
        len = lstrlen(str);
        while(pos < len)
        { 
            if(*p1 == c) 
            {
                result = pos;
                return result;
            }
            p1++;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      //Right
      pos = len = lstrlen(str);
      p1 = str;
      p1 += len;
      while(pos >= 0)
      {
          if(*p1 == c) 
          {
              result = pos;
              return result;
          }
          p1--;
          pos--;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is start for?

Answer (score 4):

Here are my comments:

Functionality:

- Remove the superfluous start parameter.
- Remove all needlessly complex (and slow) pointer arithmetic.
- Use the standard wcslen() function from wchar.h
- Position 0 is a valid array index, replace it with an invalid one if value not found.

Performance:

- Only call the strlen function once.
- Minimize the code inside the if/else statement.

Readability and style:

- str isn't modified by the function, so make it const (const correctness).
- Rewrite the loop to a conventional one.
- Only return once from a function.
- Replace all "magic numbers" with constants or enums.

-

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
  DIR_POS,
  DIR_NEG 
} dir_t;


#define NOT_FOUND -1


int myInstr (const wchar_t*  str,
             wchar_t         c,
             dir_t           dir)
{
  int start;
  int end;
  int step;
  int length;
  int i;
  int result = NOT_FOUND;

  length = wcslen(str);

  if(dir == DIR_POS)
  {
    start = 0;
    end   = length;
    step  = 1;
  }
  else /* if (dir == DIR_NEG) */
  {
    start = length - 1;
    end   = -1;
    step  = -1;
  }

  for(i=start; i!=end; i+=step)
  {
    if(str[i] == c)
    {
      result = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}


int main()
{
  wchar_t str [] = L"1234567890";

  printf("%d\n", myInstr(str, '3', DIR_POS)); // prints 2
  printf("%d\n", myInstr(str, '6', DIR_NEG)); // prints 5
  printf("%d\n", myInstr(str, 'X', DIR_POS)); // prints -1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int myInstr(wchar_t *str, wchar_t c, int start, int dir){
int pos = 0, result = 0, len;
wchar_t *p1;
```

Names like p1 are best avoided. Its hard to guess what p1 might be for.

```
//Left
if(dir == 0)
{
    p1 = str;
    len = lstrlen(str);
    while(pos < len)
```

There is not a whole lot of point in storing the length in a variable only to use it once

```
    { 
        if(*p1 == c) 
        {
            result = pos;
            return result;
```

Just `return pos`

```
        }
        p1++;
        pos++;
```

You are keeping track of the same information twice. If you can just keep track of it once.

```
    }
}
else
{
    //Right
    pos = len = lstrlen(str);
    p1 = str;
    p1 += len;
    while(pos >= 0)
    {
        if(*p1 == c) 
        {
            result = pos;
            return result;
        }
        p1--;
        pos--;
    }
```

This is very similiar to the other cases. See if you can't combine the cases.

```
}
return 0;
```

This seems a poor choice to indicate failure to find. What if it was found at position 0?

Here is my untested version of your code:

```
int myInstr(wchar_t *str, wchar_t c, int start, int dir){
    int step;
    wchar_t * position;
    wchar_t * end;

    if(dir == 0)
    {
        position = str;
        end = str + lstrlen(str);
        step = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        position = str + lstrlen(str) - 1;
        end = str;
        step = -1;
    }

    while(position != end)
    {
        if(*position == c)
        {
            return position - str;
        }
        position += step;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Reverse direction may need a tweek. 1) position/end identical 2) reading one past the end (on first element).

Comment: @LokiAstari, corrected. But of course anybody who pulls my untested code deserves what they get.

Comment: "`There is not a whole lot of point in storing the length in a variable only to use it once`"  Yes there is, readability. The result of strlen() will have to be stored _somewhere_, either in your explicitly declared variable or in an invisible temporary one sneaked into the machine code by the compiler. The machine code will be the same in both cases, so by omitting the variable you haven't optimized a thing. Actually, I bet you only make things worse by calling the function inside both if and else, depending on how CPU branch prediction works.

Comment: @Lundin, I don't think you gain you readability by doing that. In my view local variables improve readability in three ways: Firstly, by providing an informative name for a value. Secondly, by splitting complex expressions up into multiple pieces. Thirdly, by replacing a non-trivial expression used multiple times.

Comment: To my mind, the first doesn't apply because the name doesn't tell me anything `strlen` doesn't. The second doesn't apply because the expression is still pretty simple. The third doesn't apply because the expression being replaced is non-trivial. The code would not be any shorter using a shared variable.

Comment: I'm certainly not attempting to optimize anything by avoiding local variables. I just don't think it helps readability. As for the performance, I wouldn't be surprised if compilers manage to hoist the strlen out the if blocks. The optimizations compilers manage are very impressive. I'm not sure how branch prediction comes into this. But certainly there could be a speed penalty for doing it in both branches.

Comment: Alright... anyway, it not only helps branch prediction if the function is only called once, but it also helps readability. Since strlen must be called every time no matter if/else, it should be outside the if statement regardless of optimization issues. See my own answer for a suggestion how to do it differently.

Comment: @Lundin, rather then just restating that it helps readability, could you explain where you disagree with my analysis of the issue?  Quote frankly, I find the version you posted much less readable then mine.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I suspect that my code will be more efficient, but that does of course depend a lot on the target architecture. As for readability, for loops are generally regarded as easier to read than while ones (and may be easier for the compiler to optimize). Multiple return statements are generally regarded as bad practice (although I don't always agree there). Those opinions aren't just mine, you can read them in coding standards such as MISRA.

Comment: @Lundin, I'll agree that a for loop would have been a better choice here. Because the initialization step was separate from the loop I didn't think to use it. While many standards disapprove of multiple returns I don't find their reasons convincing. There are cases where that's a good idea but I don't think this one of them. As for performance, benchmarks or there is no difference. ;)

Comment: @WinstonEwert Ok so now I did a rough benchmark on both our codes and their execution times were pretty much identical (GCC/Mingw, Windows XP, 10 million function calls measured with QueryPerformanceCounter). I did however manage to speed up both versions significantly by getting rid of the dir variable, which I suppose shouldn't come as much of a surprise.